# printing numeric pyramid in C starting with the highest number at top

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

Ive searched through the site about this kind of pyramid and over the internet but didnt find something that close to it, i myslef am new to coding and cant figure it out by myslef i guess.I have tried to modify others code to get the result that i want but with no success.

I have to make code that prints piramid starting with the entered number at top and then gradually expanidng with the following numbers.

**Example input: 5**

**Output:**

```
    55
   4554
  345543
 23455432
1234554321
```

I can make half of the pyramid problem is its uspide down

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
int i,j,num;
printf("number:");
scanf("%d",&num);
for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    j=num;

    for(j;j>=i;j--){
        printf("%d",j);
    }printf("\n");


}
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
number:5
54321
5432
543
54
5
```

and for the other half i tried to mirror it with small changes in the loops but 
I dont know how to get rid of some of the numbers 
Heres that Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
int i,j,num,k;
printf("number:");
scanf("%d",&num);
for(i=1;i<=num;i++){

    for(k=1;k<=num;k++){
        printf("%d",k);
    }


    j=num;
    for(j;j>=i;j--){
        printf("%d",j);
    }printf("\n");


}
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
number:5
1234554321
123455432
12345543
1234554
123455
```

Comment: To solve this kind of problems, a good idea is to take it step by step, eg. start by making it work without the left side and the spaces (much easier) and then modify the code step by step until you reach what you want.

Comment: Consider the left half of the piramid, the first line you have to print 4 spaces and a '5', the second line 3 spaces, then a '4' followed by '5' and so on. Do you know how to write a loop and how to print characters?

Comment: You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide some code to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Bob__ yes i know both, Ive added the code that i did so far and for the spaces i left them for last. Im not sure how to execute that which you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My five cents.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        const int UPPER_LIMIT = 10;

        printf( "Enter a non-negative integer number less than %d (0 - exit): ",
                UPPER_LIMIT );

        int n;

        if ( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 || n <= 0 ) break;

        if ( !( n < UPPER_LIMIT ) ) n = UPPER_LIMIT - 1;

        putchar( '\n' );

        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%*d", n - i, n - i );

            int j = n - i;
            while ( j++ != n ) putchar( '0' + j );
            while ( j-- != n - i ) putchar( '0' + j );

            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look the following way

```
Enter a non-negative integer number less than 10 (0 - exit): 9

        99
       8998
      789987
     67899876
    5678998765
   456789987654
  34567899876543
 2345678998765432
123456789987654321

Enter a non-negative integer number less than 10 (0 - exit): 8

       88
      7887
     678876
    56788765
   4567887654
  345678876543
 23456788765432
1234567887654321

Enter a non-negative integer number less than 10 (0 - exit): 7

      77
     6776
    567765
   45677654
  3456776543
 234567765432
12345677654321

Enter a non-negative integer number less than 10 (0 - exit): 6

     66
    5665
   456654
  34566543
 2345665432
123456654321

Enter a non-negative integer number less than 10 (0 - exit): 5

    55
   4554
  345543
 23455432
1234554321

Enter a non-negative integer number less than 10 (0 - exit): 4

   44
  3443
 234432
12344321

Enter a non-negative integer number less than 10 (0 - exit): 3

  33
 2332
123321

Enter a non-negative integer number less than 10 (0 - exit): 2

 22
1221

Enter a non-negative integer number less than 10 (0 - exit): 1

11

Enter a non-negative integer number less than 10 (0 - exit): 0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int baseNum;    //These global variables exist just to help the beginners to
int col;        //read the program and understand the logic involved

void print() {  //In the real word col and baseNum is passed to print
     if (col < baseNum)
        printf(" ");
     else
        printf("%d", col);
}

int main() {
    int num;
    printf("number:"); scanf("%d",&num);    //num < 11

    baseNum = num;

    for (int line = 0; line < num; ++line) {
        col = 1;
        do {                            //Left line side
            print();
        } while (++col <= num);
        do {                            //Right line side
            --col;
            print();
        } while (col);

        --baseNum;

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @TheArquitect I think it would be better if there are no global variables.

Comment: I agree. It just to help him to read and understand the logic involved.

Comment: I up-voted your answer because you are the single who helped to resolve the question.